# Accidentally Anaconda uninstall cut short

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, uninstallation, anaconda3

I accidentally stopped the Anaconda uninstalling. Now prompt is gone and Uninstall.exe is also gone and I can't seem to find a way to uninstall Anaconda now. If someone knows how can I uninstall Anaconda so I can reinstall it clean please help me.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling?

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I reinstalled Anaconda on a differente folder and ran Anaconda-clean on the conda terminal. Then I deleted the old folder and it was all good (until now at least).